# Selecting Model Based On Data Set

Tags: regression, p-value, linear-model, model, variance-inflation-factor

I am doing a project for class in which we choose a data set and use SAS to analyze potential models to predict the response variable. I ran an preliminary proc reg in SAS to determine which variables in my model were sufficient, but according to the p-values all but 2 were insufficient. I don't wish to drop all those variables early on in my analysis. Would it be reasonable to start off by dropping variables with a high vif?